# Packaging a self developed linux app

Tags: linux, bash, installation

I've created a own linux application that I, in time, will distribute to the masses through my upcoming internet service.

My question is... How should I package the binary? My initial thought was to simply write a bash-script for the user to run with:

```
sudo wget -nv -O https://some-server/install-script.sh -P /tmp/ && sudo /tmp/install-script.sh
```

which downloads the binary which places the binary in /opt/software-name/binary-name and also writes a systemd service file, creates config file etc.

The finished product on the client machine should consist in a binary, configfile and a systemd service file.

I'm guessing that this can be done in a more professional (easier?) way? I'm of course aiming for making this as easy as possible for the end user. I don't need help with creating a bash-file doing this (I can do that myself) but I do need help with understanding what's the best practice when distributing software, specially considering that I want this to work **cross-distributions**.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

The most professional way would be to create deb and rpm packages for Debian like or RedHat like distributions.

To create Linux packages use dpkg-buildpackage or rpmbuild tools. Both of them require control files which describe package build and installation process.

Deb/RPM package build process can be unified and simplified with CMake/CPack tools.

Once package files are created you can put them into apt/yum repository on your server. Such repository is just proper directory structure with simple index file and in case of RPM files can be easily created with `createrepo` command. If repository is available to the end user then it's enough to call `apt install packagename` or `yum install packagename` to install it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. How would that make it easier for the end user? Or is it simply because "this is how you do it"?

Comment: This way your application is delivered to the end user in the same way as other packages available in the distribution.
Very important point is that application installed from package can be listed by system tools like `dpkg  -l` `rpm -qa` together with other installed packages. Thus it can be easily removed or upgraded. System tools know about every installed file of such application.

On the other hand applications installed with custom scripts are a bit hidden. User who does removed installation script has no idea which files to remove to completely remove the application etc.

Comment: True, but since the user is first required to add my repo and then calling the packet install command, it feels that I'm adding unnecessary complexity to the whole thing.

Comment: Once the repository is added user has access to all new versions of you application. It's definitely much easier for user to call package upgrade/removal then manual upgrade/removal. And finally it's professional way to go.

Comment: Ok. Let's say that I follow your advice... Would deb and rpm be sufficient to cover most distributions? Do you know any good "deb/rpm for dummies"-guides that will get me started?

Comment: I've never found any packaging for dummies guide. It takes a wile to get to know with necessary tools. My experience is that the easiest and most universal way to go is CMake/CPack (http://www.cmake.org) which from developer point of view gives one interface for all package generators. Not only deb/rpm distributions but also OS X or Windows.